# Set dynamic data in react

Tags: reactjs

I have got series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) .I would set the data of Library statically and everything is fine, but Library is going to be dynamic and the data will be sent from another page to this page by ajax request  How to set data of Library dynamically?

```
const Library = [{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc25', 'hotelinfo': {'name': 'Korston Hotel', 'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Korston Hotel Moscow', 'hotelid': 1011702.0, 'hotelimage': 'htl207110100001', 'countryid': 1002035.0, 'ecountryname': 'Russia', 'countryname': '', 'cityid': 1182348.0, 'ecityname': 'Moscow', 'cityname': '', 'star': 4.0, 'services': 'H.B', 'desc': ' ', 'enable': '1', 'delete': '0'}, 'information': {'viewname': ''}, 'validatedate': {'fdate': '1397-12-01', 'tdate': '1397-12-29', 'tdateid': 10592.0, 'fdateid': 10564.0}}, 'families': [{'availablerooms': [{'info': {'room': 'Single', 'cost': 2400.0, 'availability': 'onrequest', 'withbed': 0.0, 'withoutbed': 0.0, 'adults': 1.0, 'infant': 0.0, 'roomid': '1011702_483587', 'double': '0'}}], 'optionId': '1011702_483587@@@5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc25', 'totalPrice': 2400.0, 'services': 'H.B', .....]
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state = {
            library: null,
            perPage: 1,
            currentPage: 1,
            maxPage: null,
            filter: "",
        };
    }
   .
   .
   .
 }
 ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I try below code but there is an error : ReferenceError: Library is not defined.

```
Component { 
    constructor(props){ 
        super(); 
        this.state = { 
            Library:[],
            library: null,
            ..... 
        };
    }
        componentDidMount() {
          $.ajax({ 
          url:"/test1.bc", 
          type:"post",
                data:{
                    cityid:"1182348",
                    fdate:"1397-12-13", 
                    tdate:"1397-12-16", 
                    userid:"0",
                    rooms:JSON.stringify({"rooms":[{"adultcount":"1","childcountandage":"0"}]}),
                },
       success:(result)=>{ 
       this.setState({Library: eval(result)}); } 

     }) }
}
```

Comment: what's the exact error , ReferenceError: $ is not defined or ReferenceError: Library (Library state) is not defined ?    if your error is first one  you have to include jQuery and reference it,    if it's  a second one make sure your doing $.ajax in componentDidMount()

Comment: The Second one. I try componentDidMount() , but has not solved the problem yet:|

Comment: "/test1.bc" is this your local file

Answer (score 0):

You set the data dynamically in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, instead of initializing it in the `constructor` or as instance variables.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const data = {};

  // fetch the data via $.ajax, fetch, or axios, etc

  this.setState({data: data});
}
```

for your case its something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url:"/json.bc", 
        type:"post",
        data:{ 
        cityid:"1182348",
        rooms:JSON.stringify({"rooms": [{"adultcount":"1","childcountandage":"0"}]}), 
    },
    success: result => { 
        this.setState({library: eval(result)}); // set this to 'library' instead of 'Library', since you set the variable name as 'library' in the constructor
    });
}
```

Comment: I use your code but I don't know why json.bc doesn't load? and yhere is no error in console tab.

Comment: its because you didn't implement a catch method probably. Anyways check if the relative path to the URL is fine (since you know where json.bc file is).